# dot-prop vulnerability fix in docker file node npm

Tags: node.js, security, npm, dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    make
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash - \
    && apt install -y nodejs \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I want to upgrade dot-prop version alone to 5.2.0, without the changing the npm package,

```
-- npm@6.14.6
  +-- abbrev@1.1.1
  +-- ansicolors@0.3.2
  +-- ansistyles@0.
    ........
    ,.........
| +-- configstore@3.1.2
  | | +-- dot-prop@4.2.0
```

So I added the following command.

`RUN npm install dot-prop@5.2.0 -g`

Now there are two versions of it,

1st version is latest version which i have installed

```
    /usr/lib
+-- dot-prop@5.2.0
| `-- is-obj@2.0.0
`-- npm@6.14.6
  +-- abbrev@1.1.1
```

2nd version inside npm dependency

```
-- npm@6.14.6
      +-- abbrev@1.1.1
      +-- ansicolors@0.3.2
      +-- ansistyles@0.
        ........
        ,.........
    | +-- configstore@3.1.2
      | | +-- dot-prop@4.2.0
```

How do i change the version of dot-prop inside npm, since 4.2.0 version is there ,so does the twistlock report will mark it as vulnerable eventhough i have installed latest version?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've found, `dot-prop` if part of `configstore` which is part of `update-notifier` and included in NPM.  So I guess that to update `dot-prop` all of the packages will need to be updated to point to the new version of dot-prop.

I've tried `RUN npm update -g dot-prop` and doesn't update it

The node package manager will need to be updated.  Even the latest version that was updated 15 days ago still point to the same `dot-prop` version.

https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/package-lock.json#L854

A PR has been created for that’s fix in NPM CLI https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/1682